# blank entry field problems

Tags: php, html, forms

I am building a long form and my last 4 entries don't work. I just keep on getting a blank entry. Everything but the last 4 fields works, I haven't changed the way I have done anything. The only way I can make it work is by changing the input from `wheelbarrow` to `surfboard` but that's not what I want.

```
<tr>
  <td height="42">Swing (dism)</td>
  <td><input name="swing" type="text" id="swing" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
  <td>Work Bench</td>
  <td><input name="workbench" type="text" id="workbench" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="42">Trampoline (dism)</td>
  <td><input name="tram" type="text" id="tram" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
  <td>Whipper Snipper</td>
  <td><input name="ws" type="text" id="ws" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="42">Wheel Barrow</td>
  <td><input name="wheelbarrow" type="text" id="wheelbarrow" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

That is the html part and below is the php part:

```
<tr> 
<td>&nbsp;Mirror</td>
<td>&nbsp;$mirror</td>
<td>&nbsp;Tv Cabinet</td>
<td>&nbsp;$tvcabinet</td>
<td>&nbsp;Dinning Chair</td>
<td>&nbsp;$dinningchair</td>
<td>&nbsp;Surfboard</td>
<td>&nbsp;$surfboard</td>
<td>&nbsp;Whipper Snipper</td>
<td>&nbsp;$ws</td>
```

```
<tr> 
<td>&nbsp;Picture</td>
<td>&nbsp;$picb</td>
<td>&nbsp;TV Lge Screen</td>
<td>&nbsp;$tvlge</td>
<td>&nbsp;Dinning Table</td>
<td>&nbsp;$dinningtable</td>
<td>&nbsp;Ping Pong Table</td>
<td>&nbsp;$pingpong</td>
<td>&nbsp;Work Bench</td>
<td>&nbsp;$workbench</td>
```

The only 2 things that don't work here is `whipper snipper` and `work bench`. I haven't added the whole script because it is very long.

I hope this isn't confusing and I hope I can get some help.

Comment: I think we need more of your code to really help. Where are you setting the values of your variables? Have you spelled the form field name correctly in the PHP portion of your code so it matches what gets passed by your form submission? (If they aren't exact matches, you won't get any values)

Comment: i did have one that was spelt wrong, but it looks like there is just to many inputs in the form. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to check.

1. Are you sure you have not duplicated the names that dont work?
2. If you have a truly large number of inputs in this form, check your
   php.ini file for this definition

   max_input_vars

If your form contains more than that number of inputs, they just get truncated at that number. So increase the number to be in excess of the number in your form.

Comment: It is the last 4 fields so i think your right. it might just be easier to delete them. cheers